# Is it possible to get a parent's id in a ActiveRecord model's scope method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scopes

Say you have a Game model which `belongs_to` two Teams.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :home_team, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: "home_team_id"
 belongs_to :away_team, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: "away_team_id" 

end
```

A team can find its games by using this method of the Team class:

```
def games
  Games.where("home_team_id = ? OR away_team_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
end
```

and then use `@team.games.upcoming` by using this method of the Game class:

```
def self.upcoming
  where("starts > ?", DateTime.now)
end
```

The scopes get merged together, and it worked perfectly.

Now I'm trying to write a method that will allow me to do this:

```
@team.games.won
```

which *could* be checked by

```
@team.games.where("home_team_id = ? AND home_score > away_score OR away_team_id = ? AND away_score > home_score", ?????, ?????)
```

but I can't figure out how to pass in the correct team id where the ?????'s are. Is this even possible? I have no idea what to search to find this, if it's been asked before.

Comment: What's the signature of the method you're trying to write? Are you trying to get all games that were won by a given team? If so, that makes most sense as an instance method rather than a class method.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you'd use `@team.id` for each, like @EricAndres said.

However, you'll also want some additional parenthesis in your `where` clause to make it work right:

```
@team.games.where("(home_team_id = ? AND home_score > away_score) OR (away_team_id = ? AND away_score > home_score)", @team.id, @team.id)
```

**Update**

Since this is on the `Game` model, how about a class method on that model called `won_by` which takes a `team`:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.won_by(team)
    where("(home_team_id = ? AND home_score > away_score) OR (away_team_id = ? AND away_score > home_score)", team.id, team.id)
  end

end
```

Comment: I don't have access to @team to use in this method, as it's a class method of the Game model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@team.id` for each.

Comment: I don't have access to @team to use in this method, as it's a class method of the Game model.

Comment: That's not specified in the question. An edit to make that clear would be nice.

Comment: Well I did mention that I'm trying to be able to write @team.games.won which I think implies that it has to be a Game model class method. But I'll edit it in anyway.